# PHPMailer sending twice

Tags: wordpress, phpmailer

Inherited some PHPMailer code in a WordPress theme and cannot figure out why the following is sending 2 duplicate emails with the same timestamps in the body.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->From = $_POST['form_email'];
$mail->FromName = $_POST['form_name'];

$mail->addAddress('craig@myemail.com'); // Send email to

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = 'Entry';
$mail->Body    = '
    <p>Submitted: '.date('d/m/Y H:i:s').'</p>
';

if ( !$mail->send() ) {
    $response->result = false;
}
```

Comment: instead of $mail use $my_mail and check. $mail is too generic name might be used by wordpress and something internally might be conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

Timestamps only have a 1-second resolution, so it's very likely that this is a double request by your browser - it's a common problem with some extensions. It's easy to test - stick a random number on the end of your subject:

```
$mail->Subject = 'Entry '.rand();
```

If the numbers in your messages are different, you'll know your script is being run twice.

It also won't help that you're forging the from address, that's a good way to cause delivery problems - [read the PHPMailer docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).